# How to show pop on seleted text

Tags: datatable, popup

[image: Data Table]
Above is the data table in which I am pulling data from database and displaying in different column.
as shown in the screen.
I want to show pop at every failed record which will show reason for failed record.
but I am confuse how do I do that.since all the data are dynamic how do i select the that data. for an example `121` ,`2` and `72` are failed, so I need to show a pop after clicking on `121`,`2` and `72`. As we can see in failed column we have 0 also. then if user click on zero it should not allow to open popup. 
list is dynamic I can get more than 100 failed records. so at every failed records I need to show pop.

**Popup would have table containing four columns. for an example `a b c d.`**

```
 1. How do I identify `121` `2` `72` or any other failed record.
 2. How do I show a pop-up after clicking on failed records.
```

this is the code for `Data Table`

```html
  var oTable =  $('#example')
    .dataTable(
      {
      "processing" : true,
      "serverSide": true,
         "autoWidth" : true,
      "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
      "ajax" : {
        "url" : '//myurl',
        "dataSrc" : ""
        },
        "columns" : [   
                         
           {
             "data" : "recordcount"
           },         
           {
             "data" : "record failed"
    ]       } 
}
```

Since we are getting the data in compact form. how to know which are failed.

I am beginner, trying to learn new things. I dint have any idea how to achieve this. please help me.

Comment: what kind of popup? title, popover, tooltip, modal ...? Bootstrap?

Comment: yes - that is a given, but what *kind* of "popup" do you have in mind? "popup"'s can be many different things, depending on who you ask, thats why I ask. There is no such thing as "popup"'s built into dataTables.

Comment: ok .. I need to show the reason why the record was failed and some more  information. overall In need to show a table in pop

Comment: Yes, it is very easy to understand, and very easy to answer that - but what is a "pop"?

Comment: I am really sorry. I dint get you properly. I explained you my requirement What i want to do. Popup in the sense, When I click on failed record something should popup a where I can display some info as mentioned.it can be anything if we can display pop table as a popup than its cool

Comment: @davidkonrad Popup would have table containing four columns. for an example a b c d.